# react navigation v4 - different transition animation for the same stack | React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to implement something and it is very confusing.
In our app, everything that is inside the same stack has a left to right transition and navigating from different stacks causes an top to bottom transition.

Example of a stack that I assume I need to change:

```
const BackupNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    ZoomTutorial: ZoomTutorial,
    ZoomScanComplete: ZoomScanComplete,
    BackupSuccess: BackupSuccess,
}, 
{headerMode: 'none'});
```

The flow is you do a face scan and you show a success screen.
Now I added a screen where you verify your backup. inside the BackupSuccess screen.
So I added a new screen in this navigator stack but now when I press the verify button (goes back to the ZoomTutorial screen, the transition is from right to left. It goes back a screen in the navigator. I want it to show a top to bottom transition.

What is the best practice here? Should I create a new stack for this? How would the app know in which stack am I in? Is there a simpler solution? I can't find a way to define the transition according to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify what animation you want in `navigationOptions` for the each screen that you want the animation for:

```js
import { TransitionPresets } from 'react-navigation-stack';

// ...

static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Profile',
  ...TransitionPresets.ModalSlideFromBottomIOS
}
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#pre-made-configs